# Trying to display a sequence of numbers beginning from 1 using loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, input

I'm trying to write a program that accepts an integer from 5 to 9 from the user. If the user enters 6, the output to the user will be:

1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5 6

6 5 4 3 2 1

6 5 4 3 2

6 5 4 3

6 5 4

6 5

6

I tried using a loop like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < no; i++) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < no; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print(no);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But the output I got was:

666666

666666

666666

666666

666666

```
import java.util.*;
public class numberSequence
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number in the range 5 to 9: ");
        int no = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        if(no < 5 || no > 9)
            System.out.println("Please enter a number in the range 5 to 9.");
        else
        {
            // continuing from here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, did you **think** about the solution before writing the code? `j` needs to go from 0 to `i`, and **not** from 0 to `no`.

Comment: Also you're only printing out `no`, which is the input number. So if you input `6`, your output is all `6`s

Comment: I'm betting that if you'd called your variable 'no' something like 'terminationValue' you'd have quickly spotted the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop would be -

```
for(int i = 1; i <= no; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print(j+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
for(int i = 1; i <= no; i++){
    for(int j = no; j >= i; j--) 
    {
        System.out.print(j+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Input - no = 6

Output -

1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5 6

6 5 4 3 2 1

6 5 4 3 2

6 5 4 3

6 5 4

6 5

6

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 for loops, the first one for increasing until value of n, the 2nd one for decreasing from value n to 1.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
    public class numberSequence
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a number in the range 5 to 9: ");
            int no = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            if(no < 5 || no > 9)
                System.out.println("Please enter a number in the range 5 to 9.");
            else
            {
                for(int i = 1; i <=no; i++) 
                {
                    for(int j = 1; j <=i; j++) 
                    {
                        System.out.print(j);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

                for(int i = no; i > 0; i--) 
                {
                    for(int j = i; j >=1; j--) 
                    {
                        System.out.print(j);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
654321
54321
4321
321
21
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
         System.out.print(j);
     }
     System.out.println("");
}
for (int i = no; i >= 1; i--) {
     for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
         System.out.print(j);
     }
     System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are printing "no" , you should print "j".

program print desire output is

public class Simple {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int no= 6;
    for(int i = 1; i <= no; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
        {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    for(int i = no; i >= 1; i--) 
    {
        for(int j = i; j >= 1; j--) 
        {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

  }
}
```